# Issue with multiple classes per element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Ok so I have this code that toggles the slide function. I would like to add a second class to the links that open the individual sections of content to read head="collapsed, head", however when I do this the JQuery stops working and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    * { margin:0; padding:0; } /* a simple reset */
    .head, li, h2 { margin-bottom:15px; }
    .head { display:block; }
    .content { display:none; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.head').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.content').slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><a onclick="expandAll()"><strong>Expand All</strong></a></div>
<div><a onclick="collapseAll()"><strong>Collapse All</strong></a></div>
  <ul>
    <li>
     <a href='#' class='head'>Heading 1</a>
  <div class='content'>Content 1
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <a href='#' class='head'>Heading 2</a>
  <div class='content'>Content 2</div>
</li>
<li>
  <a href='#' class='head'>Heading 3</a>
  <div class='content'>Content 3</div>
</li>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem, works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/aBRHV/

Comment: Are you serious? `jquery/1.3.2`?

Comment: I made a Fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/N654K/  
However I could not reproduce your error. Could you provide more details please?

Comment: "JQuery stops working"?? could u be more specific? How can jQuery stop working?

Comment: @MentholBonbon I had no idea that Fiddle site existed, relatively new to this. That's awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no comma between multiple classes. So you should just add

```
class="collapsed head"
```